# definite integration - solution breakdown

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, distribution-theory, gamma-function

$$ \int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x(y+1)}dx$$ $$=-\frac x {y+1}e^{-x(y+1)}|_0^{\infty} +\frac 1 {y+1} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x(y+1)}dx$$ $$=\frac 1{(y+1)^{2}}.$$

Unfortunately i cannot follow the steps. **I guess integration by parts has been used?**

**How can Gamma density approach be applied here?**

Comment: Yes. Integration by parts with $f(x):=x$ and $g'(x)=e^{-x(y+1)}$ works. ($g(x):=-\frac{1}{y+1}e^{-x(y+1)}$

Answer (score 0):

by parts, with $a=y+1$

$u=x$ and $v'=e^{-ax}$.

$$\int_0^Xxe^{-ax}dx=$$

$$\Bigl[x\frac{-1}{a}e^{-ax}\Bigr]_0^X-\int_0^X\frac{-1}{a}e^{-ax}dx$$

$$\frac{Xe^{-aX}}{a}+\frac{1}{a}\Bigl[\frac{-1}{a}e^{-ax}\Bigr]_0^X=$$

$$\frac{Xe^{-aX}}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{e^{-aX}}{a^2}$$

now take the limit when $X\to+\infty$.